# How can I attach to a process in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Is there a quick way to attach to process in vs.net 2008 (attaching to the IIS process)?

Everytime I stop the debugger, and want to re-run I have to go to Debug -> attach to process -> choose the aspnet_web.exe

Answer (score 10):

You can record a macro to do it. In VS2005 I did this:

- ctrl-shift-R (start recording)
- ctrl-alt-P (attach to process)
- select the process
- OK
- ctrl-shift-R (stop recording)

To play back the temporary macro, ctrl-shift-P. It generated the following code in the Macros IDE:

```
Sub TemporaryMacro()
    Try
        Dim dbg2 As EnvDTE80.Debugger2 = DTE.Debugger
        Dim trans As EnvDTE80.Transport = dbg2.Transports.Item("Default")
        Dim dbgeng(1) As EnvDTE80.Engine
        dbgeng(0) = trans.Engines.Item("Native")
        Dim proc2 As EnvDTE80.Process2 = dbg2.GetProcesses(trans, "<machine-name>").Item("cmd.exe")
        proc2.Attach2(dbgeng)
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

You can convert this to a permanent macro in the Macros IDE and then bind it to a keystroke in the Tools-Options-Keyboard pane.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Alt+P and select aspnet_web.exe from the list if you're using Win XP.